# Capture group with python regex not capturing

Tags: python

Im trying to gain an understanding of capture groups using this example:

```
sentence = "the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"

re.search(r'\S+\s+\S+',sentence)

<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 9), match='the quick'>
```

I can see this matches as follows:

```
re.search(r'\S+\s+\S+',sentence).group()

'the quick'
```

I want to add a match group for the word 'quick' so I try this:

```
re.search(r'\S+\s+\(S+)',sentence)
```

Which gives an error:

```
error: unbalanced parenthesis at position 10
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You have a typo. You are escaping the '(' but you want to escape the `S`. Switch `\(S+)` to `(\S+)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a typo, but I'll still provide an explanation.

You are *escaping the opening parenthesis* making it matching a literal `(`, which makes the closing parenthesis at the end of the expression without an opening part, replace:

```
\S+\s+\(S+)
```

with:

```
\S+\s+(\S+)
```